# Regex substitution does not replace match character for character

Tags: regex, pcre

I am trying to use Regex to dynamically capture all numbers in a string such as 1234-12-1234 or 1234-123-1234 without knowing the number of characters that will occur in each string segment. I have been able to capture this using positive look ahead via the following expression: [0-9]*(?=-). However, when I try to replace the numbers to Xs such that each number that occurs before the last dash is replaced by an X, the Regex does not return X's for numbers 1:1. Instead, each section returns exactly two X's. How can I get the regex to return the following:

```
1234-123-1234 -> XXXX-XXX-1234
1234-12-1234 -> XXXX-XX-1234
```

instead of the current

```
1234-123-1234 -> XX-XX-1234
```

?

[Link to demo](https://regex101.com/r/cTu7VP/1)

Comment: What language/tool are you using?  You might be able to do this with a regex _replacement_, but a pure regex by itself doesn't do this.

Comment: Sure it can - replace a single digit, with a lookahead of `[0-9]*-`, with an `X`.

Comment: Tim we are using ruby gsub and learning Regex expressions to match strings. It's a class so the idea is to only use regex for a learning exercise to target the substring.

Comment: @jasonharper, could you clarify the full expression? Using that look ahead doesn't seem to change the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that by placing the * directly after the digit match, more than one digit would get replaced with a single X. And then zero digits would get replaced with a single X. Therefore any number of digits would be effectively replaced as two X's.

Use this instead:

> [0-9](?=.*-)